# Conan package manager and CMakePresets.json? Is it possible?

Tags: python, cmake, conan

I've just started using Conan package manager. Do you know is it possible to somehow call cmake with presets from conanfile.py? The current implementation is the following:

```
...

def build(self):
    cmake = CMake(self)
    cmake.configure()
    cmake.build()

...
```

I've managed to call CMakePresets.json by the following code (but it seems hacky - I don't like it).

```
...

    def cmake_configure(self)
        if self.settings.os == "Linux":
            self.run("cmake --preset=linux .")
        elif self.settings.os == "Macos":
            self.run("cmake --preset=macos .")
        elif self.settings.os == "Windows":
            self.run("cmake --preset=windows .")
        else:
            raise ConanInvalidConfiguration("Unsupported OS")

    def build(self):
        self.cmake_configure()
        self.run("cmake --build .")

...
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conan maintains backward compatibility with older CMake versions. Even for Conan 2.0, the community has reached a consensus (https://github.com/conan-io/tribe/pull/4) that CMake 3.15 is the base to support, that means that Conan should work by default with CMake 3.15 (or newer). If Conan used cmake presets, which is cmake>=3.19, then that wouldn't be satisfied. At some point, Conan will add some tools to manage presets, but at the moment there is nothing built-in.

However, using presets, might not be necessary, as [CMakeToolchain](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake.html) will generate a `conan_toolchain.cmake` file that can help with the integration (the CMake generator is still necessary to be passed in command line).

Comment: For further discussions, it might be better to submit an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. And is it possible to use my own toolchain per OS? I cranked up the default optimization settings with my own and it seemed cleaner if I provide toolchains rather than "bake in" with target_compile_options. Anyway it seems I have to think over the design again, because it's a mess now. I've spent so much time on the build and I haven't written yet a single real C++ code! 

Comment: Yes, if you are using the ``CMakeToolchain`` integration, then you have ``[conf]`` for that, that you can define either on the command line or better, in the profile file, to automatically inject or completely replace the user toolchain. With ``conan config list`` you can see available configs, the relevant ones are ``tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:user_toolchain`` and ``tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:toolchain_file``. This is all experimental, but it is the future integration that will survive in 2.0 and is already in 1.X, and already more flexible than previous.